# Lane Departure Warning System for Autonomous Driving- TypeError: expected non-empty vector for x

Tags: python-3.x, video

I'm using this program from github https://github.com/JunshengFu/driving-lane-departure-warning . I am trying to run a video file and i get below errors

File "/home/ramakrishna/PycharmProjects/Lanedect/driving-lane-departure-warning-master/lane.py", line 602, in process_frame

```
detector(binary_sub, ploty, visualization)
```

File "/home/ramakrishna/PycharmProjects/Lanedect/driving-lane-departure-warning-master/lane.py", line 554, in detector

```
left_fit, right_fit = full_search(binary_sub, visualization=visualization)
```

Code:

```
def detector(binary_sub, ploty, visualization=False):

left_fit, right_fit = full_search(binary_sub, visualization=visualization)

left_fitx = left_fit[0] * ploty**2 + left_fit[1] * ploty + left_fit[2]
right_fitx = right_fit[0] * ploty**2 + right_fit[1] * ploty + right_fit[2]
std_value = np.std(right_fitx - left_fitx)
```

File "/home/ramakrishna/PycharmProjects/Lanedect/driving-lane-departure-warning-master/lane.py", line 294, in full_search

```
right_fit = np.polyfit(righty, rightx, 2)
```

Code :
 # Fit a second order polynomial to each

```
left_fit = np.polyfit(lefty, leftx, 2)
right_fit = np.polyfit(righty, rightx, 2)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 555, in polyfit

```
raise TypeError("expected non-empty vector for x")
```

Code :

```
if x.size == 0:
    raise TypeError("expected non-empty vector for x")
if y.ndim < 1 or y.ndim > 2:
    raise TypeError("expected 1D or 2D array for y")
```

TypeError: expected non-empty vector for x

Comment: but... where is the code associated to that error?

Comment: # Fit a second order polynomial to each
    left_fit = np.polyfit(lefty, leftx, 2)
    right_fit = np.polyfit(righty, rightx, 2)
    # Visualization

Comment: def detector(binary_sub, ploty, visualization=False):

    left_fit, right_fit = full_search(binary_sub, visualization=visualization)

    left_fitx = left_fit[0] * ploty**2 + left_fit[1] * ploty + left_fit[2]
    right_fitx = right_fit[0] * ploty**2 + right_fit[1] * ploty + right_fit[2]
    std_value = np.std(right_fitx - left_fitx)

Comment: hold on hold on my dear please! wait a minute, please, take a minute, you can edit the actual question, and please, add all the code INTO the question, after the code, put the stack error

Comment: Hope this will do..

Comment: https://github.com/JunshengFu/driving-lane-departure-warning/blob/master/lane.py

Comment: The above link has complete code.

Comment: Fantastic! now this is a good question :), help is comming

Comment: what libraries are you using in the proyect?

Comment: I din get you..I am running through Pycharm.It has its libraries.I am using Python 3.4 version

Comment: I would like to add that..The code works perfect when I use the given video with the code online. But when I try to add my own video file or different Images/videos from net similar to it , it gives this error.

Comment: mmm I see, but where did you take the code from? what's the library name? what's the format of the original video input? and the size? the duration? it is a .mp4 or some?

Comment: I took code from the below given link

Comment: https://github.com/JunshengFu/driving-lane-departure-warning/

Comment: Its mp4 and 1280 x 720 and even my video file is the same. The duration of the original is 50 sec but mine is 33 sec

Comment: I din get what you mean by library name? I am new to python sorry...!!

Comment: sometimes you import code from libraries, but it is not your case, you clone the code from github... mmm I have used this code before, so for now I cannot say much, I will try to download it and run it myself

Comment: My video size is 34.7 MB and theirs is 25.3 MB

Comment: well, you have a hint there! why your video if is shorter than theirs, is bigger in MB? Try to find what kind of video the code supports

Comment: I too imported few libraries when i got errors initially..like mat-lib,numpy etc..

Comment: How can I find out?

Comment: Even theirs is .mp4

Comment: Could it be because they use monocular camera? I took video from my mobile.

Comment: Could be, did you try with another video from the web? Or record with another device

Comment: No. I dont have any

Comment: How abt pi camera?

Comment: Please let me knw if you could find any other error. :)

Comment: Hi, I got the output and my video is running. Thanks a lot for your inputs and help..!! The problem was the white lane was detected properly in between the video.I took another video and ran. It worked. :D

Comment: Congratulations! you can post it, answer your own question step by step, and further users will be grateful :)

Comment: i am also working similar kind of project and based on my experience and knowledge i learned about this , this error generally occurs when the array passed to the polyfit() is none or [] . In short u need to change the area of interest for cropping the image and it should do . Also if u need further help in cropping the desired area u may ask again.